# RSelenium Error: Can't Connect to Host; Selenium Server is not running

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs

I am getting the following error: "Error in checkError(res) : 
  Couldnt connect to host on http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.
  Please ensure a Selenium server is running."

I'm using a mac version 10.9.5, and downloaded all of the latest versions of packages and java. My code is:

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
setwd(Path to selenium standalone file)
pJS <- phantomjs(pjs_cmd = "/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs")
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
Sys.sleep(5)
remDr$open(silent = FALSE)
```

And then I get the mentioned error. I've tried using the "java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar" command in the terminal (after us the cd command to navigate to the correct directory). I've tried changing my port in the remoteDriver() function (to 4444, 5556). I've tried various Sys.sleep() times (up to 20 seconds). When I googled this error, most of the fixes were for FireFox or Windows, and not applicable to using PhantomJS

What else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RSelenium::phantom` function is deprecated. This had a `pjs_cmd` argument which I think you refer to above. You can use the `rsDriver` function from the `RSelenium` or the `phantomjs` function from the `wdman` package:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
# no need for remDr$open a phantom browser is already initialised
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com/ncr")
....
....
# clean up
rm(rD)
gc()
```

Alternatively using the `wdman` package

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
pDrv <- phantomjs(port = 4567L)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = 4567L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com/ncr")
...
...
# clean up
remDr$close()
pDrv$stop()
```

Comment: The second option worked for me (though the first option still gives me the same error). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jdharrison: when I tried your 1st option, I got this error: `"Could not open phantomjs browser.
Client error message:
  Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
   Detail: A new session could not be created.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details."`. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!